# Kafka Post Deployment - Handling ever-growing clients

Tags: apache-kafka

We have setup a Kafka Cluster for High Availability and distributed data load. The current consumers and producers specify all the broker IP addresses to connect to the cluster. In the future, there will be the need to continuosly monitor the cluster and add a new broker based on collected metrics and overall system performance. In case a broker crashes, as soon as possible we have to add a new broker with a different IP.

In these scenarios, we have to change all client configurations, a time consuming and stressful operation.

I think we can setup a Config Server (e.g. Spring Cloud Config Server) to specify all the broker IP addresses in a centralized manner, so we have to change all in one place, without touching all the clients, but I don't know if it is the best approach. Obviously, the clients must be programmed to get broker list from config server.

There's a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Worth pointing out that the "bootstrap" process doesn't require giving every single broker address to the clients, really only the first available address in the list is used for the initial connection, then the `advertised.listeners` on all the broker configs in the cluster, is what the clients actually use

The answer to your question is to use service discovery, yes. That could be Spring Could Config, but the more general option would be Hashicorp Consul or other service that uses DNS (Kubernetes uses CoreDNS, by default, for example, or AWS Route53).

Then you edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` of each machine (assuming Linux) the client is running on to include the DNS servers, and you can simply refer to `kafka.your.domain:9092` rather than using IP addresses

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
You're right when you say that is not required to specify every single broker, but I'm putting in worst case scenario where all brokers are crashed.
We use Eureka as service discovery for microservices communication, Docker Swarm as orchestrator and on-premise Kafka Cluster. Both microservices and external application (i.e many kafka clients) connect to cluster. Can I try to use Eureka in place of Consul or other services?

Comment: I've never used Eureka, but from what I understand, it is similar, although, it requires client code changes compared to going down a layer and configuring DNS instead

Answer (score 0):

You could use a load balancer (with a friendly dns like `kafka.domain.com`), which points to all of your brokers. We do this in our environment. Your clients then connect to `kafka.domain.com:9092`.

As soon as you add new brokers, you only change the load balancer endpoints and not the client configuration.

Additionally please note that you only need to connect to one bootstrap broker and don't have to list all of them in the client configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I know, Kafka uses a binary protocol over TCP. We use Spring Cloud Gateway as reverse proxy and load balancing solution for microservice architecture. Do you mean DNS load balancing?